# Transformer for huge numeric list

Tags: python, pandas, transformer-model

hello everyone i am working on a scientific paper and have a dataset that only consists of normalized values and a label as a string.
Per label there are 1500 lines with one numeric value each.
I would like to try to use the dataset with a transformer, but unfortunately I have not been able to do it yet. Do you have an idea which Transformer model is suitable for this and how I proceed best?